# Create multiple columns in data.table with `:=` without colnames

Tags: r, data.table

I was wandering if it is possible to use the following data.table feature without providing column names:

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)[,.(mpg, cyl)]
dt[,`:=`(avg=mean(mpg), med=median(mpg))]
```

Let's say for example that I have a function that return more than one column like this

```
mfun=function(x){cbind(x^2,x^3)}
```

But if I want to assign it as new columns that specific way, R would execute function mfun twice, which is not efficient.

```
dt[,`:=`(sqr=mfunc(mpg)[,1], cub=mfunc(mpg)[,2])]
```

So, without 'work arounds', is it possible to do something similar to this:

```
dt[,`:=`(mfunc(mpg))] #this returns an error
dt[,`:=`(error2=mfunc(mpg))] #this returns an error
```

Comment: Instead of `cbind`, do `mfun <- function(x) list(x^2, x^3);
> dt[, c('sqr', 'cub') := mfun(mpg)]`

Comment: That would only work if I am using a custom function, but I guess I can convert the result of other functions to data.table before assignment, right?

Comment: The issue with the `cbind` is that it is a `matrix` and suppose the output `type`s are different, it will create issues later

Comment: Ricardo, in support of akrun's first comment, please see the section on the `j` argument in `?data.table`: "As long as `j` returns a list, each element of the list becomes a column in the resulting `data.table`."

Comment: And regarding your "without providing column names", see `?:=`: you need a `LHS`, but perhaps you can generate the character vector programmatically.